# A Desperate Loss (Spider Solitaire)

Tags: cards

This is a Spider Solitaire problem inspired by a hand I played today on my phone.  Hopefully it’s easier than previous puzzles (where I got no satisfactory response). It is assumed the reader knows the rules and terminology of Spider, which is easily found online (different apps have slightly different rule variants but that is irrelevant here). I have just dealt the last row of cards from the stock.

There are four questions. **To qualify for the Green Tick (TM) you need to answer at least one correctly** and hope nobody else does better than you do  I know the answer to at least one question is YES.

- Q1: Is it possible to turn over one face down card? (do not attempt to reveal more than one card)
- Q2: Is it possible to build a complete suit?
- Q3: Is it possible to achieve Q1+Q2 if you were allowed to swap the 7$\clubsuit$ and 5$\heartsuit$ in column 5?
- Q4: Is it possible to achieve Q1+Q2 if you were allowed to call the rank and suit of the next face-down card?

[image]

Text version:

? Js Th 9s 8c 6h

? Kc 5s 2c

???? Kh Jd Kc 3h 9d 8d Ad

???? 4s 3d 2h Ac 3s 2c As Qs

5h 7c

?? Kh Qd Jh Th Kd Qd 9c 8s 7s 6d 5d 4d 3d 2d Ad 9h 8h 7h 4h

Jc Tc 9c 8c 7c 6c 5c 4c 3c Qh

Kd Qc Jd Tc 9d 8d 7d 6s 5c 4c 3c 2s Ah Jh

9h 8h 7h 6h 5h 4h 3h 2h Ah As

Ks Qs Js Ts 9s 8s 7s 6s 5s 4s 3s 2s Ac Qh

Stock = 0, suits removed = 0

Checksum: 6 + 4 + 11 + 12 + 2 + 21 + 10 + 14 + 10 + 14 = 104